# How to have 2 categories of AuraHandledException in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Unplanned exceptions that escape an `@AuraEnabled` method get converted to e.g.:

```
[  
    {  
        "message":"An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: ...-... (...)"
    }
]
```

and `DmlException`s get converted to e.g.:

```
[  
    {  
        "message":"Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Error message added to field: []"
    }
]
```

As [Returning Errors from an Apex Server-Side Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_custom_errors.htm?search_text=AuraHandledException) explains, converting those to an `AuraHandledException` allows a specific message to be returned. But as far as I can see there is no way to add additional information e.g. `AuraHandledException` can't be extended to add extra data fields; it just has a message string.

I'd like to have 2 or more categories of `AuraHandledException` so my client-side code can present the information appropriately. All I can think of is something like a magic prefix in the string or to make the message string itself JSON so the extra information can be encoded. Is there a better approach I have missed?

Comment: I'd probably be tempted to JSON-encode the intended data in the message attribute, then deserialize it on the far end.